# Codenameone - IOS debug build getting failed : Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Tags: codenameone

I keep getting this error after I try to build on ios :

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_kCFStreamSSLPeerName", referenced from:
-[ca_weblite_codename1_net_impl_NativeSocketImpl createSocket:param1:] in ca_weblite_codename1_net_impl_NativeSocketImpl.o
"_kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain", referenced from:
-[ca_weblite_codename1_net_impl_NativeSocketImpl createSocket:param1:] in ca_weblite_codename1_net_impl_NativeSocketImpl.o
"_kCFStreamSSLLevel", referenced from:
-[ca_weblite_codename1_net_impl_NativeSocketImpl createSocket:param1:] in ca_weblite_codename1_net_impl_NativeSocketImpl.o
"_kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings", referenced from:
-[ca_weblite_codename1_net_impl_NativeSocketImpl createSocket:param1:] in ca_weblite_codename1_net_impl_NativeSocketImpl.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
Ld /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build9106977163875219348xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Main/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Main.app/Main normal arm64
(1 failure)
Process return code is 65
Failed xcodebuild step

[image: Build Hints]

Comment: This is due to the websocket cn1lib. What's are the ios.* build hints defined in your project?

Comment: sure.. I've updated the question @ShaiAlmog

Comment: It looks like you're missing all the settings from the websocket lib. Did you install it via extensions?
Did you use the refresh cn1libs action afterwards? Did it succeed?